Bitwise swapping the internal representation of two simple objects, even if they are not of a trivially copyable type
In another question you can see the motivation for this one:
Implementing bitwise swap for MyString
However, the two answers I got contradict each other so here is a simplification of the question.

I've created SimpleClass, a simple class, that consists only of trivially copyable member(s).
I declared a copy constructor so that SimpleClass is not trivially copyable.
I created two SimpleClass objects: s1 and s2.
I only want to swap s1 and s2 by what I claim is a valid assumption that the layout of the two is the same even if objects have padding.

I know SimpleClass is not trivially copyable. However, I think the following code has a defined behavior. Can anyone justify or contradict me by quoting the C++ standard?
#include <cstring>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct SimpleClass {
    int m; 
    SimpleClass() : m(rand()){} 
    SimpleClass(const SimpleClass& o) : m(o.m) {} 
};

int main() {
    static_assert(!std::is_trivially_copyable_v<SimpleClass>);
    SimpleClass s1; 
    SimpleClass s2; 

    constexpr size_t SimpleClass_SIZE = sizeof(SimpleClass);
    alignas (SimpleClass) char tmp[SimpleClass_SIZE]; // alignas probably not necessary
    std::memcpy(&tmp, &s1, SimpleClass_SIZE);
    std::memcpy(reinterpret_cast<void *>(&s1), &s2, SimpleClass_SIZE);
    std::memcpy(reinterpret_cast<void *>(&s2), &tmp, SimpleClass_SIZE);
}

See the code here: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/Pn3KjcsPG
Question framing/limitation:
We are discussing the behavior of using a class that

Has only trivially copyable member(s).
Has no virtual member function/pointer - as in this case using the copied object will be UB.


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
